# Can't get rid of "this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90" warning

Tags: c, warnings, constants, unsigned, c89

I'm using the FNV hash as a hashing algorithm on my Hash Table implementation but I'm getting the warning in the question title on this line:

```
unsigned hash = 2166136261;
```

I don't understand why this is happening because when I do this:

```
printf("%u\n", UINT_MAX);
printf("2166136261\n");
```

I get this:

```
4294967295
2166136261
```

Which seems to be under the limits of my machine...

Why do I get the warning and what are my options to get rid of it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
unsigned hash = 2166136261u; // note the u.
```

You need a suffix `u` to signify this is an unsigned number. Without the `u` suffix it will be a signed number. Since

```
2166136261 > 2³¹ - 1 = INT_MAX,
```

this integer literal will be problematic.

Comment: I assume that doesn't impose any implications in the FNV hashing algorithm and that it will always work as it should?

Comment: Note that the code is well-defined and complies with all versions of C Standard -- the suffix is only "need"ed to silence a warning which , in this instance, is spurious.