# Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)

Tags: c, floating-point, integer, long-integer, minimum

I was working on an embedded project when I ran into something which I thought was strange behaviour. I managed to reproduce it on codepad (see below) to confirm, but don't have any other C compilers on my machine to try it on them.

Scenario: I have a `#define` for the most negative value a 32-bit integer can hold, and then I try to use this to compare with a floating point value as shown below:

```
#define INT32_MIN (-2147483648L)

void main()
{
    float myNumber = 0.0f;
    if(myNumber > INT32_MIN)
    {
        printf("Everything is OK");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The universe is broken!!");
    }
}
```

Codepad link: http://codepad.org/cBneMZL5

To me it looks as though this this code should work fine, but to my surprise it prints out `The universe is broken!!`.

This code implicitly casts the `INT32_MIN` to a `float`, but it turns out that this results in a floating point value of `2147483648.0` (positive!), even though the floating point type is perfectly capable of representing `-2147483648.0`.

Does anyone have any insights into the cause of this behaviour?

**CODE SOLUTION**: As Steve Jessop mentioned in his answer, `limits.h` and `stdint.h` contain correct (working) `int` range `define`s already, so I'm now using these instead of my own `#define`

**PROBLEM/SOLUTION EXPLANATION SUMMARY:** Given the answers and discussions, I think this is a good summary of what's going on (note: still read the answers/comments because they provide a more detailed explanation):

- I'm using a C89 compiler with 32-bit `long`s, so any values greater than `LONG_MAX` and less or equal to `ULONG_MAX` followed by the `L` postfix have a type of `unsigned long`
- `(-2147483648L)` is actually a unary `-` on an `unsigned long` (see previous point) value: `-(2147483648L)`. This negation operation 'wraps' the value around to be the `unsigned long` value of `2147483648` (because 32-bit `unsigned long`s have the range `0` - `4294967295`).
- This `unsigned long` number *looks* like the expected negative `int` value when it gets printed as an `int` or passed to a function because it is first getting cast to an `int`, which is wrapping this out-of-range `2147483648` around to `-2147483648` (because 32-bit `int`s have the range -2147483648 to 2147483647)
- The cast to `float`, however, is using the actual `unsigned long` value `2147483648` for conversion, resulting in the floating-point value of `2147483648.0`.

Comment: fwiw, the universe isn't (as) broken if you use gcc 4.2.1.  (So you're probably right about the compiler.)

Comment: are you on a 32 bit system? note that - is an operator. it is not part of the integer literal.

Comment: Can't reproduce with gcc 4.2.1. What compiler are you using?

Comment: I can reproduce this with gcc 3.1. Yeah, I know that's a bit old :-) With gcc 4.6 on a 32-bit system `gcc -std=c90` produces the observed behaviour, `gcc -std=c99` works "as expected".

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941261/warning-this-decimal-constant-is-unsigned-only-in-iso-c90 which contains some standards discussion.

Comment: I assume that you added the `L` suffix to your constant specifically to avoid the problem described in the answers. However, on your platform `int` and `long` have the same size, which is why the overflow persists. You can add `LL` suffix instead and the overflow should go away (assuming `long long` has larger range)

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, *not* `void main()`.

Comment: Slight correction to your explanation: it's not true that *any* values with `L` suffix are `unsigned long`, it's specifically values greater than `LONG_MAX` and less or equal to `ULONG_MAX`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C89 with a 32 bit `long`, `2147483648L` has type `unsigned long int` (see 3.1.3.2 Integer constants). So once modulo arithmetic has been applied to the unary minus operation, `INT32_MIN` is the positive value 2147483648 with type `unsigned long`.

In C99, `2147483648L` has type `long` if `long` is bigger than 32 bits, or `long long` otherwise (see 6.4.4.1 Integer constants). So there is no problem and `INT32_MIN` is the negative value -2147483648 with type `long` or `long long`.

Similarly in C89 with `long` larger than 32 bits, `2147483648L` has type `long` and `INT32_MIN` is negative.

I guess you're using a C89 compiler with a 32 bit `long`.

One way to look at it is that C99 fixes a "mistake" in C89. In C99 a decimal literal with no `U` suffix *always* has signed type, whereas in C89 it may be signed or unsigned depending on its value.

What you should probably do, btw, is include `limits.h` and use `INT_MIN` for the minimum value of an `int`, and `LONG_MIN` for the minimum value of a `long`. They have the correct value *and* the expected type (`INT_MIN` is an `int`, `LONG_MIN` is a `long`). If you need an exact 32 bit type then (assuming your implementation is 2's complement):

- for code that doesn't have to be portable, you could use whichever type you prefer that's the correct size, and assert it to be on the safe side.
- for code that has to be portable, search for a version of the C99 header `stdint.h` that works on your C89 compiler, and use `int32_t` and `INT32_MIN` from that.
- if all else fails, write `stdint.h` yourself, and use the expression in WiSaGaN's answer. It has type `int` if `int` is at least 32 bits, otherwise `long`.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for providing the standard.

Comment: Small nit, it might be better to explicitly state that `In C99, 2147483648L has type long long` also assumes 32-bit `long`.

Comment: Interestingly and informatively, [limits.h](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/i386/limits.h) (first online source I could find...) uses the `#define INT_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)` mechanism [recommended by WiSaGaN](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536486/325514).

Comment: Great info, thanks for that it was very informative. I am using the TI CGT v3.2.2 for MSP430 (embedded project), but I'm not really sure if this is C89 or something else. I'm now using the limits.h header for my defines so thanks for that tip too. As I said in my comment to the other answer, I completely missed that this could be the case because I was using this define without problem (assigning it to variables, passing it to functions, printing it out, etc) until I tried to convert it to a float. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13):

Replace

```
#define INT32_MIN (-2147483648L)
```

with

```
#define INT32_MIN (-2147483647 - 1)
```

`-2147483648` is interpreted by the compiler to be the negation of `2147483648`, which causes overflow on an `int`. So you should write `(-2147483647 - 1)` instead.
This is all `C89` standard though. See Steve Jessop's answer for `C99`.
Also `long` is typically 32 bits on 32-bit machines, and 64 bits on 64-bit machines. `int` here gets the things done.

Comment: More specifically, writing -2147483648 causes the compiler to evaluate it as -(2147483648). The literal in brackets overflows, resulting in -(-2147483648) = 2147483648. The universe then shatters.

Comment: The moral is that there are no negative integral literals, only (unsigned) integral literals and unary minuses.

Comment: arguing solely on the bitpatterns on two complement, it should end up as negative. probably an optimization pass interferes here.

Comment: @KerrekSB Exactly. I haven't checked the C standard. I suppose there should be something explicitly saying this.

Comment: Be careful about generalizations on the type `long` - it's not always 64-bits on 64-bit systems (Win64 for example).

Comment: @MichaelBurr You are right. It's the typical case, not a sure thing. I'll edit it later.

Comment: Ah yes this solves the problem. I didn't even consider that this could have been the case, mainly because I did things like assign INT32_MIN to a 32-bit int variable, pass INT32_MIN to a function, and print INT32_MIN all without any issues. What would cause this difference in behaviour?

Comment: @WiSaGaN The code to demonstrate can be found at: [http://codepad.org/JkRoyKRe](http://codepad.org/JkRoyKRe). My compiler (TI CGT v3.2.2 for MSP430) seems to behave the same way as codepad in this situation.

Comment: @avanzal That's interesting. If you define `int a = INT32_MIN;`, then pass `a` to where it would previously fail, namely `printf("As float (straight): %f (FAIL)\n", (float)a);`, you would get correct result. It seems there's weird things the compiler are doing.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: it's not that weird: if you assign the out-of-range positive value `2147483648` to `int` then the result is implementation-defined, but it's not uncommon to see it wraparound to `-2147483648`.

Comment: @SteveJessop Very interesting, the wraparound was the last piece of information I needed for this to 'click' in my head. I think I understand what's going on now, so thanks to everyone! I've added a summary to my original post. I think it's accurate, but feel free to edit it or let me know if it's not.

Comment: @WiSaGaN: A lot of code expects `unsigned long` to wrap at 2^32 and will behave very badly if it does not do so.  The fundamental problem is that C has consistently failed to provide unsigned types with predictable wrapping behavior (it still doesn't have them, since a standards-compliant compiler could legitimately have a 64-bit `int` type but include a `uint32_t` type; on such a compiler, multiplying together two `uint32_t` values could turn the CPU into a heap of molten slag).