# What's the point of including -std=c++0x in a G++ compile command?

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, g++

I have recently started learning C++ and, since I'm on Linux, I'm compiling using G++.

Now, the tutorial I'm following says

> If you happen to have a Linux or Mac environment with development
>   features, you should be able to compile any of the examples directly
>   from a terminal just by including C++11 flags in the command for the
>   compiler:

and tells me to compile using this command: `g++ -std=c++0x MY_CODE.cpp -o MY_APP`.

Now, what I'm wondering, what is the point of the `std=c++0x` flag? Is it required, or can I just run `g++ MY_CODE.cpp -o MY_APP`?

Comment: Haven't used GCC in a while, but last time I checked, the default mode for C++ code was C++03, so if you wanted to use C++11, you had to specify this flag explicitly. (BTW, why don't you try it?)

Comment: Use `-std=c++11` GCC versions that don't support that are getting more outdated.

Comment: `-std=c++11` turns on certain language features that are no available on older versions of standard C++

Comment: This is supposed to become unnecessary with gcc-5, which should default to -std=gnu++11. The switch hasn't happened yet though, so who knows...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, GCC compiles C++-code for `gnu++98`, which is a fancy way of saying the C++98 standard plus lots of gnu extenstions.

You use `-std=???` to say to the compiler what standard it should follow.
Don't omit `-pedantic` though, or it will squint on standards-conformance.

The options you could choose:

```
standard          with gnu extensions

c++98             gnu++98
c++03             gnu++03
c++11 (c++0x)     gnu++11 (gnu++0x)
c++14 (c++1y)     gnu++14 (gnu++1y)
```

Coming up:

```
c++1z             gnu++1z (Planned for release sometime in 2017, might even make it.)
```

GCC manual: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Standards.html#Standards

Also, ask for full warnings, so add `-Wall -Wextra`.

There are preprocessor-defines for [making the library include additional checks](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_macros.html):

- [`_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/ext_compile_checks.html) to add additional compile-time-checks for some templates prerequisites. Beware that those checks don't actually always do what they should, and are thus deprecated.
- [`_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/debug_mode.html). Enable the libraries debug-mode. This has considerable runtime-overhead.
- `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` Same as above, but checks against the standards requirements instead of only against the implementations.

Comment: So, `-pendantic` makes it so...g++ is less strict?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: No `-pedantic` makes it so that GCC actually remembers you asked for standard conformance. Otherwise, it is far too lenient.

Comment: Excellent presentation.  But since you mention `-Wall -Wextra`, you should also mention `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC -D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS`, which do the same thing for the library.  They should be present in every debug build.  (For release builds, the first two can impact performance enormously, and so may have to be removed.)

Comment: And the related `-std=` options for C: `c90`, `c99`, `c11` and `gnu90` (the default for C), `gnu99` or `gnu11`.

Comment: Concept checking is deprecated and breaks valid code. You can mention it, but only with a big warning sign...

Comment: @MichaelBurr When you mentioned c90 that brought up a compiler warning I got later on. I ran `g++ -Wall -o "game_stats2" "game_stats2.cpp"` and this warning came up: `game_stats2.cpp:34:2: warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90 [enabled by default]`. Is this because I didn't include the `-std=c++0x` flag?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness: In C90 a decimal integer constant without a type suffix that can't fit in a `long int` will be an `unsigned long int` int (if possible).  That doesn't happen in C99 or any of the C++ standards. I suspect that you have such an decimal literal - depending on the standard in effect, it might be a `long long int` (C99/C++11 or later) or undefined behavior (C++98, C++03). The warning is just that: warning you that you might be getting something you aren't expecting. For more detail see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20910712/12711

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) standard (and you are right to want that), but C++11 made a huge progress w.r.t. its older C++98 standard.

But old versions of GCC (i.e. GCC 4.8 or earlier) where not finalized before the standard itself (so they accepted the `-std=c++0x` flag). I strongly recommend (if you want C++11) to use the latest version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), that is [GCC 4.9](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/). A bug fixing GCC 4.9.2 release appeared at end of october 2014. So use it please, and pass it the `std=c++11` flag to tell the compiler you want C++11 conformance.

I actually suggest to pass `std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g` to get C++11, all warnings, and debug info. Once you have debugged your program (with `gdb`, and you'll better also use a recent version of `gdb`!) you might ask the compiler to optimize with `-O2` (and perhaps `-mtune=native` if you want to optimize for your own computer)

Comment: So, should I download GCC 4.9.2 from [here](mirrors.concertpass.com/gcc/snapshots/LATEST-4.9/)? That seems to be a Nightly/Bleeding edge release...where is a Stable 4.9.2 that I can download?

Comment: You might download the source code from [GNU GCC mirrors](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html), then you'll need to configure, build and install it. Compile in a build tree outside of the source tree, and read the [installation instructions](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/)

Answer (score 1):

Source for your reference:

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test main CPP" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

> build.sh

```
rm demoASI*
echo "**cleaned !!**"

##### C++ 11 Compliance #####
# type ONE
g++ -o demoASI_1 -std=c++0x main.cpp
echo "**rebuild-main-done (C++ 11 Compilation) !**"

# type TWO
g++ -o demoASI_2 -std=c++11 main.cpp
echo "**rebuild-main-done (C++ 11 Compilation) !**"

##### C++ 11+ Compliance #####
# type THREE
g++ -o demoASI_3 -std=c++1y main.cpp
echo "**rebuild-main-done (C++ 11+ (i.e. 1y, but not C++14) Compilation) !**"

###### C++ 14 Compliance  ######
# type FOUR
g++ -o demoASI_4 -std=c++14 main.cpp
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "**rebuild-main-done (C++ 14 Compilation) !** :: SUCCESS"
else
    echo "**rebuild-main-done (C++ 14 Compilation) !** :: FAILED"
fi
```

Now, execute the script as;
`./build.sh`  (assuming build.sh has execution permission)

You can first check the version of your `g++` compiler, as;

> g++ --version

The version of g++, after 4.3, has support for the [c++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Please see, for [c++14](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) support info in compiler.