# How to fix this array used as initializer error?

Tags: c++, error-handling, g++, g++4.9

save.cpp

```
#include "save.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
Save::Save()
{
}
```

I've commented all the functions and removed the contend out from Save::Save but it doesn't affect the error. 
save.h

```
#ifndef SAVE_H
#define SAVE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class Save
{
    public:
        Save();
        void vDisplay();
        char cDecode();
        bool bFileExists(const string& crsFileName);
        const char ccTab = 9;
        const char ccHelp[5] = "help";
        const char ccNo[3] = "no";
        const char ccStart[6] = "start";
        const char ccQuit[5] = "quit";
        const char ccYes[4] = "yes";
};
#endif // SAVE_H
```

I use g++ 4.9 and compile in C++11 and it gives me this error on the 6th line of save.cpp, altough, I've checked it but I'm new to c++ and not quite sure, this isn't an initializer at all.
It seems to be an compiler bug caused by the non-static data member initialization of constant members I want to be available to the whole class.

Comment: Show us your header file, please.

Comment: I also think that this should compile and am puzzled why it doesn't

Comment: You don't really need to specify the size of your `const char` arrays. Once you assign values to them (like you do), the compiler will compute it automatically.

Comment: Thats not my problem my dear Sir.

Comment: Just to be sure: It's not an initializer?

Comment: Unrelated, but you need to `#include <string>`.

Comment: For now it works just as fine with string.h but I'd like to read your argument.

Comment: You are using `const string&`, so you need the right include. Anyway, to solve your problem, compile in C++11 mode.

Comment: @juanchopanza the problem reproduces in C++11 (now that the example is complete): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15cc564b3f1e2c92

Comment: @user2079303 Interesting. [gcc seems fine with that on ideone](http://ideone.com/z4r2Df). Also with a recent clang.

Comment: @juanchopanza also works in coliru with newer gcc, appears to be a compiler bug.

Comment: @user2079303 It works if I remove the other members.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is confusing. It points to the constructor (which indeed doesn't even have an initializer list), even though the real culprit is this line (and the similar lines following it):

```
const char ccHelp[5] = "help";
```

GCC [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) says that the feature is supported since 4.7, but 4.9 apparently fails to compile your program. That appears to be a compiler bug. Remember that C++11 support was experimental until GCC 5.1. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15cc564b3f1e2c92) is your program reproducing the compiler bug in 4.9 and [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abaccc1187cb1b19) is your program compiling fine in 5.1.

So, your options are 1) upgrade your compiler or 2) use uglier form of the initialization, which appears to work in 4.9:

```
const char ccHelp[5] = {'h','e','l','p','\0'}; // ugly :(
```

---

As a sidenote: You use `std::string`, but you forgot to include `<string>` where `std::string` is defined.

Comment: Why is everyone unhappy with me using string.h instead of string? It seems to perfectly work so far so what is wrong?

Comment: @M.Brückmann except for Jose's deleted answer, nobody has mentioned your use of string.h. You may keep it in your code if you wish even though you don't use anything from the header. What is wrong is that you use `std::string` but don't include `<string>` which is where `std::string` is defined. Just because it happens to work (because another header happened to include `<string>`), doesn't mean that it's OK, or that it won't stop working at any time the standard library is changed.

Comment: I am actually incuding `<string.h>` which, as far as I know, is also meant to define `std::string` or am I wrong?

Comment: @M.Brückmann Why do you thing that `<string.h>` defines `std::string`? It does not.

Comment: I heard it somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

In-class initialization:

```
const char ccHelp[5] = "help";
```

is only legal since C++11.

Comment: I know but you're not answering my question.

Comment: @M.Brückmann I am answering your question if you are not, in fact, using C++11. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822712/whats-the-point-of-including-std-c0x-in-a-g-compile-command for details.

Comment: @M.Brückmann You never said you're compiling in C++11 mode in your question.

Comment: I am using C++11 otherwise I'd have other problems to face

Comment: @Eutherpy To eliminate all misunderstandings I've now included it into my question.