# Cannot compile my c++ program using g++ in linux

Tags: compilation, header, g++

I am working in a small laberinth game using C++. My problem: I like Visual Studio Code for Linux, and when I run my program, I get the following error:

main.cpp:2:10:fatal error: Player.h: No such file or directory

## include "Player.h"

I set this project using the following folder structure:

```
Game
|-------include
         |----------GameMap.h
         |----------Map.h
         |----------MapCell.h
         |----------Player.h
|-------src
         |----------GameMap.cpp
         |----------Map.cpp
         |----------MapCell.cpp
         |----------Player.cpp
|-------main.cpp
```

This project ran in another computer I was using, and it runs also when I use codeblocks. BUt since I like to keep working in visual code, I would like to be able to compile and run my C++ code when working from Visual Studio code.

g++ -o main main.cpp

edit:

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{  
   "configurations":[  
      {  
         "name":"Linux",
         "includePath":[  
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "/home/roger/Documents/01.Curso_de_CPP/Projecto/Game_02/Headers/include/**"
         ],
         "defines":[  
            "_DEBUG"
         ],
         "forcedInclude":[  
            "/home/roger/Documents/01.Curso_de_CPP/Projecto/Game_02/Headers/include/Player.h"
         ],
         "compilerPath":"/usr/bin/gcc",
         "cStandard":"c11",
         "cppStandard":"c++17",
         "intelliSenseMode":"clang-x64"
      }
   ],
   "version":4
}
```

Comment: did you set the include path?

Comment: Sorry. I am new at C++, and don't know how to do it. I started the project using codeblocks as editor, and it finds the header files within the directory. I didn't have this linker problems before. But I don't get how to set my project in visual code so my main.cpp compiles.

Comment: maybe read up a bit on it: [C/C++ for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp)

Comment: [c_cpp_properties.json Reference Guide](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/c_cpp_properties.json.md)

Comment: I did it. And I modified the c_cpp_properties.json. I still get this error ```fatal error: Player.h: No such file or directory```

Comment: I configured the ```includePath```, and also added parameters to ```forcedInclude```

Comment: {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/roger/Documents/01.Curso_de_CPP/Projecto/Game_02/Headers/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": ["_DEBUG"],
            "forcedInclude": ["/home/roger/Documents/01.Curso_de_CPP/Projecto/Game_02/Headers/include/Player.h"],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4}

Comment: shouldn't `..\Game_02\Headers\include\..` just be `..\'Game_02\include\..`?

Comment: I corrected it. And used the flag Iinclude. But still get main.cpp: (.text+0x47): undefined reference to ‘Player::Player()’ The only way it worked was to declare the class in the main.cpp function, which is not intended, since the lesson was about creating Header Files and declaring their methods in .cpp Files

Comment: `undefined reference to ‘Player::Player()‘` means it compiles, but doesn't link correctly. The object file for `Player` isn't bein linked to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Although I sti
ll don't understand the Linker problem, I was able to solve it using this:

g++ -o main main.cpp bin/Player.o -std=c++0x -Iinclude

by reading the answer to this post:
[What's the point of including -std=c++0x in a G++ compile command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822712/whats-the-point-of-including-std-c0x-in-a-g-compile-command)