# Converting Float to Int32, with negative numbers fails, C

Tags: c, floating-point

I have the following function which is suppose to convert a floating point number to int32. The problem is that for negative numbers it just doesn't work (my if statement isn't executing). I've tried a similar program for a conversion from float to int16 and everything works just fine. Sry if this is too simple , but I just can't figure out what I'm missing and why it doesn't work for negative values.

```
#define MaxInt32 2147483647
#define MinInt32 -2147483648
…
bool CastFloatToInt32 ( float  fNumber, int32 *ConvertedValue) {
    bool CastStatus = False;

    if ( ( fNumber >= MinInt32 ) && ( fNumber <= MaxInt32 ) ) {
        *ConvertedValue = ( int32 ) ( fNumber );
        CastStatus = True;

    } else {
        if (fNumber < MinInt32) {
            *ConvertedValue = MinInt32;

        } else {
            *ConvertedValue = MaxInt32;
        }
    }

    return CastStatus;
}
```

Comment: Could this be an issue involving the sign bit?

Comment: any reason you did not use [`floor()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/floor) or [`ceil()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ceil)?

Comment: Note that `fNumber <= MaxInt32` is equivalent to `fNumber <= (float)MaxInt32`, where the conversion to `float` of `MaxInt32` rounds **up**. For the value of `fNumber` 2^31, the condition will be true and the later conversion `( int32 ) ( fNumber )` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is not clear to me in what way you are suggesting that the floating-point to floating-point functions `floor` and `ceil` would be useful. Perhaps you should expand on this remark in an answer.

Comment: I think the answer is in how `MinInt32` and `MaxInit32` are represented as float or maybe the values are wrong to begin with. How are they defined?

Comment: I can't use library functions like floor and ceil as they seem to not be recognized and defined on th FP unit of the circuit board I am working on Tim I thought about a sign bit problem too but it's weird how this works for int16, but not for int 32. I've defined MaxInt32 as "#define MaxInt32 2147483647" and "#define MinInt32 -2147483648"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see why here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910712/1073171

Thus, you can fix this code by changing your defines to either:

```
#define MaxInt32 (int32)0x7FFFFFFF
#define MinInt32 (int32)0x80000000
```

Or else:

```
#define MaxInt32 (int32)2147483647
#define MinInt32 (int32)(-2147483647 - 1)
```

The reasoning's are given in the answer I linked above. If you're using GCC, you could always move to `-std=gnu99` or similar too!

Comment: Thank you for all your help it solved my problem. I am very grateful as I was stuck on this for two days.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler parses "-2147483648" in 2 stages: text to number and then negation.

`2147483648`  is likely an `unsigned long/unsigned` value.  Negating that does not change the type and curiously retains the same unsigned integer value of `2147483648`.

Thus `fNumber >= MinInt32` is a `signed` / `unsigned` compare which converts `fNumber` to an unsigned integer before comparing.

Suggest using [@Brian Sidebotham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30593395/2410359) solution or if that is not acceptable, at least cast the `MinInt32` to its expected type.

```
#define MinInt32 ((int32)-2147483648)
```