# Warning this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int t;
    long long n = 4294967295;
    //printf("%lu",n);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run the above code, the compiler shows the following warning

> [Warning] this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Is the warning coming with `print` commented out? Because the mention of a constant has nothing to do with the variable passed to `printf`.

Comment: It may be that the rules were different in C90. I Standard C (C11), decimal literals without `u` suffix are always of a signed type, whereas hex and octal literals alternate between signed and unsigned types. (Perhaps this once used to be the behaviour for decimal literals, too?)

Comment: `4294967295` is an `unsigned int` and some old compilers might object, you could try `4294967295ll`.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347936/cant-get-rid-of-this-decimal-constant-is-unsigned-only-in-iso-c90-warning) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941261/warning-this-decimal-constant-is-unsigned-only-in-iso-c90)

Comment: @WeatherVane: Not in standard C.

Comment: What version of C was used to compile: C90, C99, C11 or what?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Only non-decimal constants are converted to unsigned if that fits. Decimals are indeed always signed by default.

Comment: @chux: Most likely either C99 or C11, according to the warning.

Comment: @Olaf in C89 (likely C90 too) unsuffixed decimal constants can be `unsigned long`.

Comment: @chux: Yes, but then the warning would be pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: Note: the `printf` has a wrong conversion type specifier. For `long long` it should be `%lld`. Otherwise you invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: @olaf yes it would, hence OP's question and the peculiar warning.  IAC, the question of compiler venison still remains for OP.

Comment: @chux I wonder about the message. As I see everything is fine, looks like an invalid warning to me. We should know the warning settings used. A correct warning would be if the `LL` constant was assigned to a smaller type, but here everything is fine (as long as `printf` is commented out).

Comment: @olaf Agree.  What we are missing is what compiler, its version and settings are unknown.

Comment: @chux I have seen this message in the past from gcc. The warning is correct information but spurious (the code is correct). It could be useful in other cases, e.g. `unsigned int y = (4294967295 + 1)/2;` changed value from C90 to C99 (for system with 32-bit int)

Comment: @M.M Interesting.

Comment: @Olaf with MSVC `sizeof 4294967295` is 4 therefore is considered as `unsigned int` and not `long long`. More non-compliance?

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm not surprised. FYI: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5

Comment: @M.M: I don't think it is correct to warn about the constant. It would be correct (and will be for `-Wconversion`) to emit a warning for the assignment to a smaller type, though. But here we have `long long` assigned to `long long`. Looks like a bug in the compiler. gcc 4.8.4 with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wconversion` (there might be redundancies) does not warn for C11, but warns for C90 about `long long` not existing in C90.

Comment: @WeatherVane MSVC (approximately) complied to C90, they never made any effort to implement C99 or C11.  I heard they might have started on that recently but I haven't been following

Comment: @M.M fortunately for MS they don't need to bother implementing variable length arrays, which are now optional! MSVC 2015 approximates to C99, I think, but no VLAs.

Answer (score 2):

In ISO C the behaviour of `4294967295` changed between C90 and C99.

In C90, on normal systems this is an unsigned value, `unsigned int` (on 32-bit system) or `unsigned long` (on 16-bit system).  However in C99 this is a signed `long long` on those systems.

You could disable this warning, or use an integer suffix to show that you understand the issue, e.g. `4294967295LL`.

Comment: Wouldn't the obvious advice be to use `4294967295U` to get an unsigned type? The width is never a problem, since it adjusts automatically as needed. The signedness is the beef of the matter.

Comment: @KerrekSB There are multiple ways... the intent is to set a value for a `long long`, so it seems natural to use the corresponding suffix. Disabling the warning is actually my preferred solution (and instead, warn on out-of-range conversion)

Comment: Oh, I see, the use case is to initialize a long long. Hm, it's a silly warning. It shouldn't show up in pedantic standards mode I'd hope. (Out of range isn't a warning, but ill-formed, I think.)

Comment: @KerrekSB out-of-range literals are ill-formed; I meant that code like OP's which is correct should get no warning, but for example `int x = 4294967295;` , which is implementation-defined, should get a warning, rendering it unnecessary for the literal to have its own warning

Comment: Note: Re; "out-of-range literals are ill-formed": Literally, `4294967295` is not a literal in C, but an integer constant.  Code can take the address of a literal, but not `&4294967295`.

Comment: @chux I think "literal" is a better word for the thing we're talking about :P You're right that the C Standard calls them "constants" though (despite the fact that they do not have `const`-qualified type)

Comment: `const` does not make an object a constant in C. C does not have symbolic constants like C++.

Answer (score 0):

For long long int, you need `%lld` format specifier:

```
long long n = 4294967295;
printf("%lld", n);
```

Using wrong format specifier `%lu` for long long int type causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: i blocked the printf statement //